# Getting zero on Using ArcPy GetCount in an Stand Alone Code Against A Feature Class in GDB in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, count

I am able to get the count of rows in Feature Class wing Python Window like

```
arcpy.GetCount_management("pipe")
```

which is properly returning the number of rows inside the pipe feature class. but in a stand alone environment by using this code

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "C:/Users/auser/Documents/ArcGIS/Projects/Electric/Electric.gdb"
count = arcpy.GetCount_management("pipe")
print(count)
```

I am always getting `0` in result back

I also tried

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "C:/Users/auser/Documents/ArcGIS/Projects/Electric/Electric.gdb/dataset"
count = arcpy.GetCount_management("pipe")
print(count)
```

By adding the `dataset` to the `env.workspace` and again I am getting the same `0` back! Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It should work. Have you tried `print(count.getOutput(0))`

Comment: Is `pipe` in a FeatureDataset?

Comment: Is `dataset` a feature dataset

Comment: Do you get expected count when the feature dataset is named something other than “dataset” (which may be a reserved word)?

Comment: Set environment extent to union of inputs and it will work arcpy.env.extent = "MAXOF". Alternative is doing this in environment settings in ArcCatalog.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the result of the GetCount tool - https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/get-count.htm

```
count = arcpy.GetCount_management("pipe").getOutput(0))
```